# Java Android Game Development

Tags: java, android

Which is the best way to develop simple android games like this one [FingerSlayer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L97TH7kOCi8)

I have tried to use simple ImageViews,TextViews,TranslateAnimations,AlphaAnimations But I understood that it isn`t the best way to create simple android games, I have tried libGDX , I could create animations there but I could not put buttons there.So which is the best way to develop games like Flappy Bird,2048,Finger Slayer etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put buttons using [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), that's actually my choice when it comes to android game development.

Comment: can I make several view in my game?

Comment: Typically, you'll have one android view, in which you'll display several libgdx `scenes`. I encourage you to read the documents/wiki. There're also several sample games available for download. Best of lucks!

Comment: and if I want to detect Sprite touch I have to write if(touch.x>Sprite.getX ........)?